# Can we save from/input data to same html file

Tags: html, file, input, save

I have a requirement where I need to produce data in table format and send the html file to team.

For example:
Column 1
list of jobs running

I have created the above with the help of HTML table.

I need to add another column "Remarks" where user can update their remarks and save the html file and share it with the team.

Is it possible with HTML, if yes may I know how to achieve this ?

I am new to HTML, please excuse me if my question is silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

HTML is a data format. You need a programming language.

Typically this would be handled by using an HTML form, which POSTs data to an HTTP server where server-side code (written in the programming language of your choice) would store it in a database.

The HTML document with the table would be rendered on demand using data from the database.

Normally, you would share a URL to the HTTP server rather than the HTML document itself (although you could download it and then share it).

Answer (score 0):

**Yes , it is possible to make changes to your own html** but you need a scripting language to do so.

I would recommend you to use **Javascript** which allows you to change html tags values based on the user input.

using the `document.getElementById().innerHTML` you can easily change the value of html tags..

Here is a link which will expalin this topic much more elaborately.

**https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp**